# Unable to log in on a single boot Ubuntu sysytem

Tags: 16.04, login

When I tried to log in I got this screen

[image]

and after a while system asked for manual log in 
and terminal opened

[image]

how can i login ubuntu

Comment: Were you trying to upgrade your Ubuntu? See my answer for a first possible step.

Answer (score 1):

Your system disk is being mounted as read-only. This usually occurs when it's found severe errors, and wants to protect the system.

Lets first check your file system for errors.

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

If for some reason you can't do the above...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted` and determine which /dev/sdaX is your Ubuntu EXT4 partition
- quit `gparted`
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdaX` # replacing X with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`